# combining a vector and int in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, vector

Say if I had a `vector<string>` already defined and filled called `test` and an `int` called `a`. If I wanted to combine these 2 into a single object called `combined` where i could do `combined[0] = test;` to initialize/retrieve the object with the vector and `combined[1] = a;` to initialize/retrieve the object with the int, what would be the best function to do so and how would I do so? I had attempted to do `vector<vector<string>, int>` but this gave me an error.
Note: I am compiling with -std=c++11 if this matters.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct_t maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>,int>`.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> test;
    int a{};
    std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>,int> combined;

    //To access elements, use `std::get`:
    std::get<0>(combined) = test;
    std::get<1>(combined) = a;
}
```

---

to answer cellsheet's comment: that function already exists, it's called `std::make_tuple()` (see also comment by fjardon on how to store this).

Btw, why do you need to extend `std::vector<std::string>` by an `int`?

Comment: As OP uses c++11 he could even write: `auto combined = std::make_tuple(test, a);`

Comment: if I were to make a function of type `std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>,int>` which I'm planning to do (sorry for not mentioning beforehand), what would the return statement look like using `test` and `a`? I would just assume `return (test, a);`? Also, if I wanted to put it in a function called `std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>,int> sample { }`, how would I store the return values in a variable from the function call?

Comment: @cellsheet: `return {test, a};` and `auto out = sample();`

Comment: If you want to name the return values, use `std::tie`: `std::vector<std::string> outTest; int outA; std::tie(outTest,outA) = sample();`.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, I think you can do this with a `std::pair`:

```
std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, int> combined;
combined.first = test; // assign vector
combined.second = a; // assign int
```

---

or simply

```
auto combined = std::make_pair(test,a);
```

Answer (score 0):

It requires (ugly) type elision:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

class X {
    public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> vector_type;
    typedef int integer_type;

    private:
    enum Type {
        TypeVector,
        TypeInteger
    };

    template <bool Constant>
    class Proxy
    {
        private:
        typedef typename std::conditional<
                Constant, const void, void>::type void_t;

        public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<
            Constant, const vector_type, vector_type>::type vector_t;
        typedef typename std::conditional<
            Constant, const integer_type, integer_type>::type integer_t;

        Proxy(vector_t& v)
        :   m_type(TypeVector), m_data(&v)
        {}

        Proxy(integer_t& i)
        :   m_type(TypeInteger), m_data(&i)
        {}

        operator vector_t& () const {
            if(m_type != TypeVector) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Type");
            return *static_cast<vector_t*>(m_data);
        }

        operator integer_t& () const {
            if(m_type != TypeInteger) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Type");
            return *static_cast<integer_t*>(m_data);
        }

        private:
        template <typename T, typename U, bool> struct Assignment
        {
            static void apply(void_t*, const U&) {}
        };

        template <typename T, typename U>
        struct Assignment<T, U, true>
        {
            static void apply(void_t* p, const U& value) {
                *static_cast<T*>(p) = value;
            }
        };

        template <typename T, typename U>
        // Attention: Use a reference - std::is_assignable<int, int>::value> is false;
        struct Assign : Assignment<T, U, std::is_assignable<T&, U>::value>
        {};


        public:
        template <typename U>
        Proxy&
        operator = (const U& value) {
            static_assert( ! Constant, "Assignment to Constant");
            switch(m_type) {
                case TypeVector:
                Assign<vector_t, U>::apply(m_data, value);
                break;
                case TypeInteger:
                Assign<integer_t, U>::apply(m_data, value);
                break;
                default: throw std::out_of_range("Invalid Type");
            }
            return *this;
        }

        private:
        Type m_type;
        void_t* m_data;
    };

    public:
    X() : m_v{"Hello"}, m_i(1) {}
    Proxy<true> operator [] (std::size_t i) const {
        switch(i) {
            case 0: return Proxy<true>(m_v);
            case 1: return Proxy<true>(m_i);
            default: throw std::out_of_range("Invalid Index");
        }
    }

    Proxy<false> operator [] (std::size_t i) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0: return Proxy<false>(m_v);
            case 1: return Proxy<false>(m_i);
            default: throw std::out_of_range("Invalid Index");
        }
    }


    private:
    vector_type m_v;
    integer_type m_i;
};

int main() {

    // Note: The Proxy has no operator []

    // const
    {
        const X x;
        const X::vector_type& v = x[0];
        std::cout << v[0] << " " << x[1] << std::endl;
    }
    // non const
    {
        X x;
        X::vector_type& v = x[0];
        v[0] = "World";
        x[1] = 2;
        std::cout << v[0] << " " << x[1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You might consider boost::any, instead.